# Maximum value of $a$

Tags: functions, polynomials, roots

$x^4+ax^3+bx^2-9x+5=0$ has 4 positive real roots. Find the maximum value of a.

I tried plotting curves by writing it like this: $x^4+bx^2+5=x(-ax^2+9)$. But somehow I cannot make the graphs intersect at 4 points. Need hints.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_rule_of_signs

Comment: Hint:Since it has 4 real root, a must be -ve and b must be +ve number.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: use that $$(x-x_1)(x-x_2)(x-x_3)(x-x_4)=x^4+ax^3+bx^2-9x+5$$ and compare the coefficients

Comment: But how will I evaluate maximum value of $a$ by comparing coefficients?

Comment: what have you got expanding These factors?

Comment: $-a=x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4$, $b=\sum x_1 x_2$, $9=\sum x_1 x_2 x_3$, $x_1 x_2 x_3 x_4 = 5$ @Dr.SonnhardGraubner

Comment: yes that is ok, since the $a_i$ are positive, you can use $AM-GM$

Comment: Oh yes, I got it. Thanks